# Complex Comparison in C

Tags: c, zoho

What error is there in this code? 
This is most confused code I ever met, please help me with this to solve

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int compare(int a, int b, int c){
    if(a-b>0&&a-c>0)
        return c;
    else
        if (b-c>0)
        return a;//what would it return?
    else
        return b;

}
int main()
{//below in printf? is it right to print this way?
    printf("%d",compare(compare(88,89,91)compare(90,41,17)compare(75,100,96)));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `//what would it return?` did you debug the code? what would it return?

Comment: Are there commas between the `compare()`s in the `printf()`?

Comment: @J...S there must be comma else the code should not compile :D

Comment: nope, it is actually an interview question! they simply asked like this! i never debug this code so far..

Comment: @Thirumalaivasan Ask your interviewer, if he can compile the code, you'll purchase his company. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted, the code does not compile because you have missing commas in the `printf` argument list.

Here is a corrected version with extra spacing to improve readability:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int compare(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (a - b > 0 && a - c > 0)
        return c;
    else
    if (b - c > 0)
        return a;//what would it return?
    else
        return b;
}

int main() {
    //below in printf? is it right to print this way?
    printf("%d\n", compare(compare(88, 89, 91),
                           compare(90, 41, 17),
                           compare(75, 100, 96)));
    return 0;
}
```

This code seems broken in many respects, beyond the initial syntax errors:

- `a - b > 0` performs an integer subtraction that can overflow: signed arithmetic overflow is specified as having undefined behavior by the C Standard. It would be simpler and safer to write `a > b` which is defined for all values of `a` and `b`.
- `compare(a, b, c)` returns `c` if `a` is the largest value, `a` if `b` is the largest and `b` if `c` is the largest... The result is therefore heavily dependent on the order of the parameters given. One may wonder if the intend was to compute the max value of a triplet instead, which would not depend on the order of the parameters.

I wonder what is really expected from the candidate facing this test.

Comment: Can you explain? i'm really confused with 3 placeholders! even the first one i got as 75, second 8, third 40? why?

Comment: Did they conduct the interview on paper?  This `compare` function is weird, it's return value does not make much sense.

Comment: In an interview, if you spot errors in the test and have the opportunity to tell the examiner in person, go ahead. If they appreciate your reading skills (a rare and valuable gift), that will be a good point. If they don't, you probably do not want to work for such a company anyway.

Comment: Yes, on paper! Anyway! Appreciate your reply thank you so much @chqrlie Can you explain? i'm really confused with 3 placeholders! even the first one i got as 75, second 8, third 40? why?

Answer (score 1):

This code should be rewritten for clarity using a simple math rule that lets you add the same number to both sides of `>`:

```
int compare(int a, int b, int c){
    if(a > b && a > c)
        return c;
    else
        if (b > c)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}
```

Now the rules are simple:

- If `a` is max of three, return `c`
- If `b` is max of three, return `a`
- If `c` is max of three, return `b`

This set of rules lets you deduce the output for all the cases that you have.

Comment: Your remark helps trying to make sense of `compare` broken semantics, but of course your modified version is not semantically equivalent because of the potential arithmetic overflow in `a - b`, `a - c` and `b - c`. Any candidate pointing this out in an interview would be seen as an extra-terrestrial.